# Bind many tables of consistent name pattern in R

Tags: r

I normally apply bind_rows() to consolidate several tables on R, as in:

```
bind_rows (TXN_MONTH_01, TXN_MONTH_02, TXN_MONTH_03)
```

My problem is sometimes I have more than 20 tables and enumerating the list of tables would be easier to something like (say if I have 9):

```
paste("TXN_MONTH_0", 1:9, sep="")
```

Question, how can I use bind_rows(), or maybe another function, to combine several tables in R that are of the same name pattern (as in "TXN_MONTH_0n" in the above)?  Thanks.

Comment: If all your tables are stored in a single folder, you could use `list.files`, something like `list.files(path = "insert/path", pattern = "TXN", full.names = TRUE)` and then use `purrr` or `lapply` to bind them all.

Comment: @user3224496 I have added another answer to suit your need in referred question. You can have a look.

Comment: @MKR Thanks.  How do i delete all the other files since it's now consolidated with out resorting to enumeration as in rm(TXN_MONTH_01, TXN_MONTH_02, ...)?

Comment: @user3224496 What do you want to delete? The object which had been created with name `TXN_MONTH_0*` etc?